# selecting date using selenium and python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I am automating the MakeMyTrip application for selecting a respective departure date. suppose I want to select 20 January 2020 how do I select

```
 driver.find_element_by_id("departure").click()
    month_from = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='DayPicker-Months']").text
    print(month_from)
```

error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message:
>   element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable at point (822, 226).
>   Other element would receive the click: ...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is an animation when you land the page.
Before using the element, you have to wait for it to be clickable.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
 EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "departure")))
```